# Building while Designer is open causes custom control to delete itself

Tags: c#, controls, windows-forms-designer, designer

I have made a custom control which derives from `PictureBox`, it basically acts as both a text area (singleline & multiline) as well as a button (with custom border colour and colours for states like normal/active/disabled).

The issue is: When I rebuild my project while the Designer is open, the first placed custom control disappears from my project (completely removes itself from .Designer.cs and not visible in Designer & properties control list).

If I first close the designer view, then rebuild and then open the designer again, the control doesn't delete itself.

What could be the cause of this?

Edit: It seems to be the `OnParentChanged` event causing this, but I'm not too sure why?

Here's all the code for my custom control: (removed code irrelevant to the issue)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class PicBox : PictureBox {
    [NotifyParentProperty(true), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
    public Color BorderNormalColor { get { return borderNormalColor; } set { borderNormalColor = value; RefreshInactiveColor(); } }
    private Color borderNormalColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 44, 44, 44);
    //Several more properties like this for other things

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        //code for updating properties
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        Form mParent = (Form)Parent;
        mParent.Move += Parent_Move;
    }
    private void Parent_Move(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Invalidate();
    }

    public PicBox() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it through trial and error.

It seems that when placing a new instance of a custom control, the parent form of the first placed instance is unset in the Designer upon building. I'm not entirely sure why this happens - I'm assuming there's no reference to the control being attached to a parent form before build, so when the designer goes through this code and attempts to get `mParent.Move`, it encounters a silent error and stops execution for the rest of the form (which would explain why only the first instance of the control breaks?).

I fixed it with this small change to check whether parent form is not null in `OnParentChanged`:

`if(mParent != null) { mParent.Move += Parent_Move; }`